# Key Pair wont get associated with the EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wrote a code which creates a KeyPair (with createKeyPair function), creates an instance (runInstance) and then tries to assign the key pair to the instance (with describeInstances).

Parameters which I passed for runInstance are :

```
var params = {
  ImageId: 'myami',
  InstanceType: 't1.micro',
  MinCount: 1, MaxCount: 1
};
```

Parameters which I passed for describeInstances are :

```
var p = {
    InstanceIds :[instanceId],
    Filters: [
    {
            Name : 'key-name',
            Values : [mykey]
    }
    ]
}
```

describeInstances function returns me :

```
{ Reservations: [] }
```

And when I check in console it shows "Instance is not associated with a key pair
This instance is not associated with a key pair. Without a key pair you will need to log into this instance using a valid username and password combination.".

What am I doing wrong? Am I not using the correct (/order of) functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the keypair to RunInstances, they can not be assigned afterwards. DescribeInstances will only describe your existing instances.

Comment: But then what's the use of providing 'key-name' in describeInstance?

Comment: When you set the key-name, DescribeInstances would return only instance created with the matching key.